# EF - 3 tier not safe

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

Supposing a classic 3 tier application. In DAL, you have a GenericRepository where T represent your POCO class and it include some method like Insert(T entity), Delete(T entity), Update(T entity) and so on. Then, your BLL (business logic class) contains something like CustomerRepositor.
Well, all rights.

Now, image your aspx page:

```
var customers = BLL.CustomerRepository.GetAll();
customers.First().Name = "some name";
```

Not good, you have to pass by CustomerRepository.Update, Insert or Delete methods in order to I can execute some validation for all CRUD operations. In this way all business logic will not works as I aspected.

I note that no-one has never thought about this, but I think is an important question. has not make sense to have business method for CRUD operation if yuo can bypass them.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking here.  Can you please clarify and update your question?

Comment: I give it a +1. Weak / not appropriate repository designs are sadly a bane of our time, these days... I have seen a lot of them and many developers seem not to think that side through.

Comment: Ok. BLL.CustomerRepository class contains Insert, Update, Delete and Save Methods. That means it execute some business and validation logic. If you chanage state of entity without call Update method I cannot execute any business logic. Look at the above code sample. you are changing name of customer directly, without call Update method. My update method can execute some validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, lets start.

```
var customers = BLL.CustomerRepository.GetAll();
```

This was a nice line of code in the last millenium. Before generics and LINQ came along. Seirously.

These days, I would expect it at least to be like this:

```
var customers = BLL.Repository<Customer>.ToList (); //IF you have to materialize
```

There is no need for an "All" method at all ;)

> Am I missing something?

To a large degree an understanding that you are still within an application, so compromises are sort of acceptable. It is not like you run a trust boundary between applications here. Second, the fact that you should have programmed a better abstraction.

```
Repository repository = BLL.GetRepository ();
var customer s repository.Entity<Customer>.ToList ();
customer[0].Name = null;
repository.ValidateU ();
repository.Commit ();
```

would be a lot better abstraction. Creation is not done with "new" but with

```
var newCustomer = repository.Create<Customer> ();
```

which then commits.

All validation can be checked in the Validate method.

At the end, this is about HOW you design your interface for the repository - and if you insist on not keeping any state (which is a valid pattern for some operations) then this opens you to problems. And yes, you can have repositories that do not do full validation - totally valid. It really depends. You may be surprised, but I work on applications mostly where the repository is often not even updated in the same transaction as the object for performance reasons, and updates are queued and then batched, while the in memory version is the relevant one for all further operations.

It shows, at the end, that a little more thinking about how to design the DAL interface is in order, and please please please stop using an approach that is totally outdated and just leads to method creep (as you need tons of methods that otherwise just disappear in generics + linq expression trees.

Comment: Ok: 1 Why do use ToList method? That way will execute large data trasmission, so I prefer return an IQueryable, so it will the programmer to decide what really achieve (where, orderBy, etc). 2. I'm newbie about 3 tiers with EF, please can you provide me some good articles?

Comment: 1: because otherwise it is a delayed element - seriously, I would not make ToList, but then Asking for ALL customers is stupid to start with - you never do that, you always have some filter. 2: read. "Building Object Applications That Work" is a start (old, C++, but gets the whole point VERY well across). Then there are the Fowler books, i.e. "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture".